# How to have a Facebook Key Hash that works to all device or mobile in android

Tags: android, facebook

Is there any way to have a Facebook Key Hash that works to all devices or mobile without putting it manually to you Facebook App? Because every time I use another device or mobile I need to put the actual Key Hash and the problem is what if someone used my Android App? then they can't use Facebook Log in because their Key Hash is not Registered to My Facebook App?

Can anyone know how to solved this issue?
Any thoughts will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Is there any way to have a Facebook Key Hash that works to all devices or mobile without putting it manually to you Facebook App??**

Key hash is based on the computer that you use to build the APK, it is not dependent on the phone it is running on. If you work on your app from only one development machine then there is only one key hash you have to worry about for your app. So, you no need to worry about the devices in which your application runs.